# dynamic content in filepath

Tags: variables, dynamic, azure-data-factory

I am currently trying to ingest from a SFTP server and within the SFTP server the directory updates on it's own and I am needing to obtain the lates updated folder. The folder name is the date in format YYYY_MM_DD - 2 days so say today is 16/03/2023 I need the dynamic content to be 2023-03-14 but I have been unable to achieve this using inbuild functions such as utcnow() I am trying to get to the directory of: dailies/domain_names_dropped_whois/2023_03_14/

Thank you, hope this is enough info :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below dynamic content in your folder name to achieve your requirement.

`@formatDateTime(adddays(utcNow(),-2),'yyyy_MM_dd')`

Give this expression in your dataset folder name like below (Here for sample I have taken ADLS dataset and folder structure will be `data/2023_03_14/`).

[image]

For sample output I have given it to a string set variable activity and you can see that I got **present date-2** as output.

[image]